# Komodo Extension

Tags: python, ide, komodo

Continuing on with my Python learning, I just installed Komodo edit, are there any recommended add ins/extensions that I should include?  Any recommendations on using it or another GUI designer (TkInter base)?

Comment: http://community.activestate.com/addons

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Komodo, integrate it with Pylint as stated [here](http://mysite.verizon.net/bcorfman/2007/02/komodo-hacks-integrating-pylint.html) (I do not know if it works with Komodo Edit, I have run it with Komodo then). It is a code checker, very useful for dynamic language like Python.

Also, there is [GUI Builder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/spectcl/), which is not an "add-in" but "add-out", it was already part of the Komodo, but it has been [released as open source](http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Mail/Message/komodo-announce/3355346).

Answer (score 1):

Komodo extension: Tab trigger for Abbreviations (http://community.activestate.com/xpi/tab-abbreviations). Can't live without it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Komodo edit is just a text editor.

For gui design I suggest [Glade-3](http://glade.gnome.org/). It is specially juicy.

Answer (score 0):

try using eclipse instead with PyDev.

Answer (score 0):

I use to install MoreKomodo and TweakUI after putting Komodo on some machine for me.